# Sum function of power series

Tags: power-series

Let the power series be given with 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3^nx^n$$
Find the sum function $f(x)$.

I know that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1+x}$$
but I'm not sure how to find the sum function. I hope you will help.

Comment: Hint:  $3^n\times x^n=(3x)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3^nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(3x)^n=\frac{1}{1-3x}$$
provided that $|3x|<1$.

Comment: Consistency is important.